# How can I add foreground blur to ENBSeries' depth-of-field in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I'm playing Skyrim with ENBSeries' DoF (depth of field) enabled.

I see some people having a foreground blur effect on their depth-of-field and I really want that effect too. How do I add such an effect?

Comment: While you are more than welcome to ask about ENBSeries on Arqade, I don't believe an HD Graphics mod warrants its own tag.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Alright, you've been here for much longer than me, so you'll know which tags belong where better than I.

Comment: Are you running a more recent enb with the Shift+Enter menu? I'm not at my computer so I can't post an answer, but I'd try messing with the options in there since you can see the effect immediately.

Comment: A screenshot would really help; it's fairly easy to alter the blur strength and focal point of the DOF shader, but I'm not entirely sure that will yield the effect you're actually thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

Close skyrim.

Open enbseries.ini and set DepthOfField=True

Save file, open skyrim.

Easier that ctrl+enter route.

Source: [ENBseries website](http://enbseries.enbdev.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=499)

[image: Where is enbseries.ini?]

[image: "I can't find DepthOfField"]